# Clip-path transition doesn't work on div when got hovered

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to change my div element to particular shape using clip-path when it is hovered. But, when I added the transition, it seems that the transition didn't do anything. This is my code

**HTML**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="ok">
      test
    </div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}

.ok{
  background: green;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  transition: 1s linear;
  font-size: 75px;
}

.ok:hover{
  clip-path: circle(35.4% at 45% 44%);
}
```

I also put my code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/zozzizzez/pen/MWEozJB)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are changing the type of clip-path, check this https://codepen.io/dippas/pen/qBPpNGL

Comment: Hmmm , I dont really get it. What did you mean "the type of clip-path"?

Comment: polygon -> circle

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Keep a circle clip-path on the non-hover state as well

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
}

.ok {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: circle(80% at 45% 44%);
  transition: .5s linear;
  font-size: 75px;
}

.ok:hover {
  clip-path: circle(35.4% at 45% 44%);
}
```

```html
<div class="ok">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.